# CNN training error in executingTensorflow Python for identification of images of dogs and cats

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

When I try to train my CNN for identifying cats and dogs  images in Python Tensorflow, first epoch is successfully executed but later an error crops up as given.Can anyone please help out for resolving this.
 I followed the blog and then moved on to adapting the CNN they had used to my problem, but it hasn't worked out very well.

There also a dataset.py file that is used to load data of cats and dogs for training. I guess the error might be due to latest Tensorflow updates according to what I read on google but I am not sure as I am a beginner for CNN type of Neural Nets.

CommandLine Log:

```
Training Epoch 1 --- Training Accuracy:  50.0%, Validation Accuracy:  43.8%,  
Validation Loss: 0.703
2018-03-05 17:14:34.438263: W c:\l\tensorflow_1501918863922\work\tensorflow-
1.2.1\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Failed to 
create a directory:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1139, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1121, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in __ 
_exit__
next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in 
raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a 
directory:
     [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, 
save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable, Variable/Adam, Variable/Adam_1, 
Variable_1, Variable_1/Adam, Variable_1/Adam_1, Variable_2, Variable_2/Adam, 
Variable_2/Adam_1, Variable_3, Variable_3/Adam, Variable_3/Adam_1, 
Variable_4, Variable_4/Adam, Variable_4/Adam_1, Variable_5, Variable_5/Adam, 
Variable_5/Adam_1, Variable_6, Variable_6/Adam, Variable_6/Adam_1, 
Variable_7, Variable_7/Adam, Variable_7/Adam_1, Variable_8, Variable_8/Adam, 
Variable_8/Adam_1, Variable_9, Variable_9/Adam, Variable_9/Adam_1, 
beta1_power, beta2_power)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1472, in save
{self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: checkpoint_file})
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 789, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 997, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a 
directory:
     [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
 DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, 
save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable, Variable/Adam, Variable/Adam_1, 
Variable_1, Variable_1/Adam, Variable_1/Adam_1, Variable_2, Variable_2/Adam, 
Variable_2/Adam_1, Variable_3, Variable_3/Adam, Variable_3/Adam_1, 
Variable_4, Variable_4/Adam, Variable_4/Adam_1, Variable_5, Variable_5/Adam, 
Variable_5/Adam_1, Variable_6, Variable_6/Adam, Variable_6/Adam_1, 
Variable_7, Variable_7/Adam, Variable_7/Adam_1, Variable_8, Variable_8/Adam, 
Variable_8/Adam_1, Variable_9, Variable_9/Adam, Variable_9/Adam_1, 
beta1_power, beta2_power)]]

Caused by op 'save/SaveV2', defined at:
File "train.py", line 177, in <module>
saver = tf.train.Saver()
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1139, in __init__
self.build()
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1170, in build
restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 689, in build
save_tensor = self._AddSaveOps(filename_tensor, saveables)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 276, in _AddSaveOps
save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 219, in save_op
tensors)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 745, in save_v2
tensors=tensors, name=name)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in 
apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Failed to create a directory:
     [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, 
DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, 
save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable, Variable/Adam, Variable/Adam_1, 
Variable_1, Variable_1/Adam, Variable_1/Adam_1, Variable_2, Variable_2/Adam, 
Variable_2/Adam_1, Variable_3, Variable_3/Adam, Variable_3/Adam_1, 
Variable_4, Variable_4/Adam, Variable_4/Adam_1, Variable_5, Variable_5/Adam, 
Variable_5/Adam_1, Variable_6, Variable_6/Adam, Variable_6/Adam_1, 
Variable_7, Variable_7/Adam, Variable_7/Adam_1, Variable_8, Variable_8/Adam, 
Variable_8/Adam_1, Variable_9, Variable_9/Adam, Variable_9/Adam_1, 
beta1_power, beta2_power)]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 205, in <module>
train(num_iteration=3000)
File "train.py", line 200, in train
saver.save(session, 'dogs-cats-model')
File "C:\Users\Diti\Miniconda3\envs\diti\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1488, in save
raise exc

ValueError: Parent directory of dogs-cats-model doesn't exist, can't save.
```

MyCode:

```
import dataset
import tensorflow as tf
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import math
import random
import numpy as np

#Adding Seed so that random initialization is consistent
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)


batch_size = 32

#Prepare input data
classes = ['dogs','cats']
num_classes = len(classes)

# 20% of the data will automatically be used for validation
validation_size = 0.2
img_size = 128
num_channels = 3
train_path='training_data'

# We shall load all the training and validation images and labels into 
memory using openCV and use that during training
data = dataset.read_train_sets(train_path, img_size, classes, 
validation_size=validation_size)


print("Complete reading input data. Will Now print a snippet of it")
print("Number of files in Training-
set:\t\t{}".format(len(data.train.labels)))
print("Number of files in Validation-
set:\t{}".format(len(data.valid.labels)))



session = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size,img_size,num_channels], 
name='x')

## labels
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], 
name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, dimension=1)



##Network graph params
filter_size_conv1 = 3 
num_filters_conv1 = 32

filter_size_conv2 = 3
num_filters_conv2 = 32

filter_size_conv3 = 3
num_filters_conv3 = 64

fc_layer_size = 128

def create_weights(shape):
return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))

def create_biases(size):
return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[size]))



def create_convolutional_layer(input,
           num_input_channels, 
           conv_filter_size,        
           num_filters):  

## We shall define the weights that will be trained using create_weights 
function.
weights = create_weights(shape=[conv_filter_size, conv_filter_size, 
num_input_channels, num_filters])
## We create biases using the create_biases function. These are also 
trained.
biases = create_biases(num_filters)

## Creating the convolutional layer
layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input,
                 filter=weights,
                 strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                 padding='SAME')

layer += biases

## We shall be using max-pooling.  
layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer,
                        ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        padding='SAME')
## Output of pooling is fed to Relu which is the activation function for us.
layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

return layer



def create_flatten_layer(layer):
#We know that the shape of the layer will be [batch_size img_size img_size 
num_channels] 
# But let's get it from the previous layer.
layer_shape = layer.get_shape()

## Number of features will be img_height * img_width* num_channels. But we 
shall calculate it in place of hard-coding it.
num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()

## Now, we Flatten the layer so we shall have to reshape to num_features
layer = tf.reshape(layer, [-1, num_features])

return layer


def create_fc_layer(input,          
         num_inputs,    
         num_outputs,
         use_relu=True):

#Let's define trainable weights and biases.
weights = create_weights(shape=[num_inputs, num_outputs])
biases = create_biases(num_outputs)

# Fully connected layer takes input x and produces wx+b.Since, these are 
matrices, we use matmul function in Tensorflow
layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases
if use_relu:
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

return layer


layer_conv1 = create_convolutional_layer(input=x,
           num_input_channels=num_channels,
           conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv1,
           num_filters=num_filters_conv1)
layer_conv2 = create_convolutional_layer(input=layer_conv1,
           num_input_channels=num_filters_conv1,
           conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv2,
           num_filters=num_filters_conv2)

layer_conv3= create_convolutional_layer(input=layer_conv2,
           num_input_channels=num_filters_conv2,
           conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv3,
           num_filters=num_filters_conv3)

layer_flat = create_flatten_layer(layer_conv3)

layer_fc1 = create_fc_layer(input=layer_flat,
                 num_inputs=layer_flat.get_shape()[1:4].num_elements(),
                 num_outputs=fc_layer_size,
                 use_relu=True)

layer_fc2 = create_fc_layer(input=layer_fc1,
                 num_inputs=fc_layer_size,
                 num_outputs=num_classes,
                 use_relu=False) 

y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(layer_fc2,name='y_pred')

y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, dimension=1)
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=layer_fc2,
                                                labels=y_true)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls, y_true_cls)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 


def show_progress(epoch, feed_dict_train, feed_dict_validate, val_loss):
acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
val_acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_validate)
msg = "Training Epoch {0} --- Training Accuracy: {1:>6.1%}, Validation 
Accuracy: {2:>6.1%},  Validation Loss: {3:.3f}"
print(msg.format(epoch + 1, acc, val_acc, val_loss))

total_iterations = 0

saver = tf.train.Saver()
def train(num_iteration):
global total_iterations

for i in range(total_iterations,
               total_iterations + num_iteration):

    x_batch, y_true_batch, _, cls_batch = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    x_valid_batch, y_valid_batch, _, valid_cls_batch = 
data.valid.next_batch(batch_size)


    feed_dict_tr = {x: x_batch,
                       y_true: y_true_batch}
    feed_dict_val = {x: x_valid_batch,
                          y_true: y_valid_batch}

    session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_tr)

    if i % int(data.train.num_examples/batch_size) == 0: 
        val_loss = session.run(cost, feed_dict=feed_dict_val)
        epoch = int(i / int(data.train.num_examples/batch_size))    

        show_progress(epoch, feed_dict_tr, feed_dict_val, val_loss)
        saver.save(session, 'dogs-cats-model') 


total_iterations += num_iteration

 train(num_iteration=3000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in the line `saver.save(session, 'dogs-cats-model')`, just after showing progress. Now to fix this, change the path from `'dogs-cats-model'` to `'./dogs-cats-model'`. This should fix it.